# How to bind IEnumerable<T> to a Crystal Report document in C#?

Tags: entity-framework, data-binding, binding, crystal-reports, ienumerable

I have problems with Crystal Report and Entity Framework. I developing a WinForm application that have only one function that get all records from a table and then fill them all in a Crystal Report.

I'm so new with CR 2010 and I've searched for a while but still didn't find a solution yet.

Let say I have a table (Customer) with the following columns:

```
ID, Name, Buy, Price
```

and a CR document:

```
ID: @ID
Name: @Name

Buy           Price
@Buy          @Price

              TotalPrice
```

Can we just bind the list of customer directly to a CR document without convert it to XML or Dataset object?

Any helps would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
CrystalReportViewer1.HasToggleGroupTreeButton = false;
        CrystalReportViewer1.HasToggleParameterPanelButton = false;
        CrystalReportViewer1.HasPrintButton = true;
        CrystalReportViewer1.HasDrilldownTabs = false;
        CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
        CrystalReportViewer1.PrintMode = CrystalDecisions.Web.PrintMode.ActiveX;

        if( Request.QueryString["type"] == "1")
        {
            CarPark_DataSet ds = new CarPark_DataSet();

            CarPark_DataSetTableAdapters.CarParkTableAdapter customersTableAdapter1;
            customersTableAdapter1 = new CarPark_DataSetTableAdapters.CarParkTableAdapter();

            //Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartDate.Text)
            //customersTableAdapter1.FillBy(ds.CarPark, Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["start"]), Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["end"]));
            customersTableAdapter1.FillBy(ds.CarPark, Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["start"]) , Convert.ToDateTime(Request.QueryString["end"]));

            objRpt = new ReportDocument();
            string reportPath = Server.MapPath("Detailed_CrystalReport.rpt");
            objRpt.Load(reportPath);

            objRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);

            ((CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)objRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["StartDate"]).Text = Request.QueryString["start"];
            ((CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)objRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["EndDate"]).Text = Request.QueryString["end"];

            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = objRpt;
            CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();

            //objRpt.Close();
        }
```